# Converting points to polygons by group

Tags: r, sf, typecast

I have a dataframe with around 40 points. They are grouped by an ID variable (their name), which four points in each group. I'm trying to turn these points into polygons, but I've had a lot of trouble with different methods in both sf and sp — currently I have them as a large sf dataframe, but I can't seem to find any function that would use a grouping variable to create polygons.

I've tried using the st_cast method, the general idea being

```
polypoints <- polypoints %>% 
    group_by("ID") %>% 
    st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>% 
    st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
    st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")
```

but the step from multipoint to multiline string leaves the geography empty — what are the steps for a process like this?

Comment: is `MULITPOLYGON` a typo in the code or just here?

Comment: please try and give us a reproducible example with sample data?

Comment: yes the "MULITPOLYGON" is just a type, I just fixed it — I'll update with some sample data shortly

Comment: Never mind think I've done it all for you see below

Answer (score 17):

You need to `summarise` after your `group_by` statement then your approach works perfectly fine. Directly from POINTS --> POLYGON, and keeping the crs (if there is one).

```
set.seed(999)
xy = data.frame(x=runif(24), y=runif(24))
xy$ID = rep(1:6, each = 4)
head(xy)

xys = st_as_sf(xy, coords=c("x","y"))

polys = xys %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

plot(polys)
```

[image]

If you want the outer polygon you can add `st_convex_hull()`

```
polys = polys %>% 
  st_convex_hull()

plot(polys)
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in several posts, you can use `aggregate()` to achieve the same result as `summarise()`, however you may still need to use `st_convex_hull()` to make geoms valid.
If you have a valid point order you need to maintain @Jean-Luc Dupouey noted that you need to include `do_union = FALSE` in the `aggregate()` call, but it's also worth noting this is an option in `summarise(..., do_union = FALSE)` (which becomes `summarise.sf()` in this context).

Answer (score 6):

Make a reproducible example:

```
> set.seed(999)
> xy = data.frame(x=runif(24), y=runif(24))
> xy$ID = rep(c(1:6), rep(4,6))
> head(xy)
           x         y ID
1 0.38907138 0.8260703  1
2 0.58306072 0.8195141  1
3 0.09466569 0.5684927  1
4 0.85263123 0.6196068  1
5 0.78674676 0.8308805  2
6 0.11934226 0.4588336  2
```

Make the data frame into an `sf` data frame:

```
> xys = st_as_sf(xy, coords=c("x","y"))
```

Then aggregate by ID, combine the points and cast to POLYGON, turn the whole thing into an `sf` data frame. In a one-liner:

```
> polys = st_sf(
  aggregate(
    xys$geometry,
    list(xys$ID),
    function(g){
       st_cast(st_combine(g),"POLYGON")
    }
   ))

> polys
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.03014558 ymin: 0.01902308 xmax: 0.9875201 ymax: 0.8690149
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  Group.1                       geometry
1       1 POLYGON ((0.3890714 0.82607...
2       2 POLYGON ((0.7867468 0.83088...
3       3 POLYGON ((0.3907724 0.52724...
4       4 POLYGON ((0.03014558 0.8162...
5       5 POLYGON ((0.1665847 0.10961...
6       6 POLYGON ((0.9074913 0.35951...
```

Looks pretty awful but that's random data for you...

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this is extremely helpful (both in solving the problem and in teaching me new ways to think about gis in R) - I have a few quick questions though. Where is the `xys` dataframe coming from? Also, trying to use this on my own data returns: `Error in st_sfc(NextMethod(), crs = st_crs(x), precision = st_precision(x)): is.numeric(crs) || is.character(crs) || inherits(crs, "crs") is not TRUE` . Not sure what is causing this, I tried including `st_crs` in the `polys` line but that didn't help either.

Comment: Just to add on to the error, using my own data won't even display the object using `view("polys")`, and says `r error 4 (R code execution error)` despite compiling properly

Comment: Oops missing line - `xys` is an `sf` data frame created from `xy` - edited in.

Comment: yes, figured that one out! still stuck on crs issue, which doesn't happen in sample issue. Not sure what's happening, tried not including crs at `st_as_sf` step but that doesn't help

Comment: Can't duplicate. If I `st_crs(xys)=4326` and then run it it works, I can even add `,crs=4326)`  in the wrapping `st_sf(` call....

Comment: I tried this with some different reproducible data (can't post anything real I'm working with due to some privacy concerns) and it seems like this must be some projection issue with the data itself and some weird irregularities (working with public data, oh well). Nonetheless I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Spacedman doesn't work any in newer versions of `sf`. I think the issue is that `aggregate` automatically handles the union of the geometries and the FUN argument is intended to handle aggregating the non-geometry columns? I also think `st_combine` produces an `sfc` output, so the geometry column ends up as a list of `sfc` objects, not a single `sfc` object?

The following approach works in `sf 1.0-1`:

```r
set.seed(999)
xy = data.frame(x=runif(24), y=runif(24))
xy$ID = rep(c(1:6), rep(4,6))


xys = st_as_sf(xy, coords=c("x","y"))

# Aggregate - which unions the points into MULTIPOINTS (default do_union=TRUE)
# and uses FUN to assign the first value in other fields
xymp  = st_sf(
  aggregate(
    xys,
    by=list(ID=xys$ID),
    FUN=function(vals){vals[1]}))

# Cast to poly
xypoly = st_cast(xymp, 'POLYGON')

# .or (more usefully?) convex hull
xychull <- xymp
st_geometry(xychull) <- st_convex_hull(xymp$geometry)

plot(xychull['ID'])
```

[image: Convex hulls of points]

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows that the solution proposed by David_O does not work properly (i.e. does not keep the order of the points provided in the dataframe):

```
library(sf)

xy = data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,1),
  y = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), 
  ID=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

xys = st_as_sf(xy, coords=c("x","y"))

# Aggregate - which unions the points into MULTIPOINTS (default do_union=TRUE)
# and uses FUN to assign the first value in other fields
xymp  = st_sf(
  aggregate(
    xys,
    by=list(ID=xys$ID),
    FUN=function(vals){vals[1]}))

# Cast to poly
xypoly = st_cast(xymp, 'POLYGON')

plot(xypoly['ID'])
```

[image]

In order for this solution to work, one has to add the option `do_union = FALSE` in the call to aggregate:

```
library(sf)

xy = data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,1),
  y = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), 
  ID=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

xys = st_as_sf(xy, coords=c("x","y"))

# Aggregate - which unions the points into MULTIPOINTS (default do_union=TRUE)
# and uses FUN to assign the first value in other fields
xymp  = st_sf(
  aggregate(
    xys,
    by=list(ID=xys$ID),
    do_union=FALSE,
    FUN=function(vals){vals[1]}))

# Cast to poly
xypoly = st_cast(xymp, 'POLYGON')

plot(xypoly['ID'])
```

[image]

It seems to be because the default option of aggregate (`do_union = TRUE`) calls st_union, and that st_union sorts its result by y.

Comment: This code works great but how does "function(vals){vals[1]}" work? I can't find documentation for vals anywhere -- is it just defined with the anonymous function?

Comment: Yes, "vals" is just the formal argument taken by the anonymous function. It could be any other name. And "vals[1]" returns the first row of values in each of the aggregated groups.